# How to iterate through the array and find sum of all products for all customers using SQL in Azure Cosmos DB -Core SQL API?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

{
"Name": "Naveen",
"Age": 28,
"IS_MEMBER": false,
"Products":[
{
"id": 1,
"NAME": "XXXX"
"COST": 5.99
},
{
"id": 2,
"NAME": "XXXX"
"COST": 4.99
}

]
}

Comment: sum of what? cost of products?

Comment: Yes , I have edited the question as well

Comment: I know that i can retrieve it using  select c.Products[0].COST for 5.99 and select c.Products[1].COST for 4.99 , But  how do i select all COST items? How do i sum all cost Items?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is,

```
SELECT SUM(a.COST) AS SumTotal
FROM a in c.Products
```

Comment: how do you expect us to provide that in answer when you dont mention that in question?

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved using "Join".
`SELECT sum(t.Cost) as SumTotal  FROM c  join t in c.Products`

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation